# GUI Jinternal frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jinternalframe

How to create jinternalframes who's action depends on each other? example suppose i have two internal frame, if i minimize one frame the second frame should occupie the rest of the Jdesktopane and vice verse. 
More in detail we can take eclipse as an example who's work space frame and program writing space frame, which depends on each other. can some one help what's the logic behind that ?
thank you in advance for replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a WindowListener to each frame, and listen for changes to the internal frame state.

```
final JInternalFrame f1, f2;
//...
f1.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
    void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) { 
       // respond to iconfiy
    }
});
f2.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
    void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) { 
       // respond to iconify
    }
});
```

As for actually iconifying the internal frame, you need to use the desktop manager corresponding to your JDesktopPane to perform the action:

```
JDesktopPane desktop;
DesktopManager mgr = desktop.getDesktopManager();
mgr.iconifyFrame(frame);
```

Comment: i understood that i need to work on WindowStateListener for internal frame, can you please post small example how do they adapt to full frame depending on other frame iconifying and deiconifying?